# How to save files from s3 into current jupyter directory

Tags: python, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook

I am working with python and jupyter notebook, and would like to open files from an s3 bucket into my current jupyter directory.

I have tried:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket')
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    key = obj.key
    body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
```

but I believe this is just reading them, and I would like to save them into this directory. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS Command Line Interface (CLI), specifically the `aws s3 cp` command to copy files to your local directory.

Comment: Thanks! Where do I specify the bucket name?

Comment: Here's a sample command: `aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/test.txt test2.txt`. So you specify the bucket name in the path.

Comment: Thanks! Are test.txt and test2.text the files in the bucket?Is there a way to copy all of them from one folder in the bucket?

Comment: test.txt is the file in the bucket test2.txt is what the file will be called after it's copied locally. You can also so `aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/test.txt test.txt`

Comment: Is there a way to do this for all of the files together?

Comment: Yes. You can copy a whole folder by using the `--recursive` flag. Here's the documentation page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Answer (score 0):

late response but was struggling with this earlier today and thought I'd throw in my solution. I needed to work with a bunch of pdfs stored on S3 using Jupyter Notebooks on Sagemaker.

I used a workaround by downloading the files to my repo, which works a lot faster than uploading them and makes my code reproducible for anyone with access to S3.

**Step 1**
create a list of all the objects to be downloaded, then split each element by '/' so that the file name can be extracted for iteration in step 2

```
import awswrangler as wr
objects = wr.s3.list_objects({"s3 URI"})
objects_list = [obj.split('/') for obj in objects]
```

**Step 2**
Make local folder called data and then iterate through list objects to download them into jupyter notebooks to a folder called data

```
import boto3
import os
os.makedirs("./data")

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
for obj in objects_list:
    s3_client.download_file({'bucket'}, #can also use obj[2]
                            {"object_path"}+obj[-1],#object_path is everything that comes after the / after the bucket in your S3 URI
                            '../data/'+obj[-1])
```

Thats it! First time answering anything on this so I hope its useful to someone.